# How to combine the results of 2 observables as properties on an object?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have two observables that both resolve to a simple string. I am looking for a non-deprecated way to take the results of 2 observables, create an object, and pass the object into another method that returns an observable.

Lets say I have the following:

```
// both are Observable<string>
name$
age$


// I want this
let body = {
  name: (string result of name$),
  age: (string result of age$)
}

this.httpClient.post<any>("some endpoint", { body: body });
```

Question:

Do I have to subscribe to the string observables before creating the object? Or would this not be best practice? The docs recommend using zip but vscode is telling me that it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to subscribe to the string observables before creating the object?

Nope :-)

You can use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) to create an observable from multiple observables, then use [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) to form the output into an object.

```js
body$ = combineLatest([name$, age$]).pipe(
    map(([name, age]) => ({name, age})
);
```

In the above example, `body$` will always emit the body object whenever either `name$` or `age$` emit a new value.

Then, you can use `body$` as a starting point for making your http call.  [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) can be used to map the incoming value (`body`) into another observable, which is then subscribed to.  The emissions from this "inner observable" are emitted.

```js
result$ = body$.pipe(
    switchMap(body => this.httpClient(url, { body }))
);
```

`result$` will emit the result of that latest http call.

Comment: Did this answer your question?